# Read javascript variable and output css change

Tags: javascript, php, css, forms

I've got a page which dynamically updates a cart via javascript. I would like to show/hide div's based off changes made to the javascript, but any onlick or event listeners reset upon the form submit, so what I need to do is create a javascript script which checks the values posted to the cart and then selects styles based on that.

My thought was to do something like this:

```
if(my-item-name == 'i-SPEED 716') {
document.getElementById("716a").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("716r").style.display = "inline";}

else {
document.getElementById("716r").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("716a").style.display = "inline";}
};
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: May I suggest having a look at the language's [documentation about the `if / else`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else)?

Comment: `if` statement syntax aside, that seems like a fine way to handle those style changes. I'd suggest looking at ways to use AJAX to post form data instead of a regular submit and the page reloading, as that would solve the issues with losing listeners.

Comment: People are getting caught up in the syntax errors. It's not clear how submit is being handled or where this `if` is being used to really provide alternatives. Showing the context of this `if` would help

Comment: yes, I spent 0 time on syntax as I'm new and slow to this. I more wanted feedback on the concept so I don't spend a bunch of time struggling with syntax if the concept is wrong.    @charlietfl: the 'my-item-id' value is getting posted to an external php file and then populating a shopping cart.

Comment: Well it's certainly not scalable for a lot of individual values. You could check for existence of `document.getElementById(my-item-name +"a")` and set style if it exists to make things more generic

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your getting the value of your cart items. You could try this format :

```
 if(cartItems.length > 0){

    /*do something....*/

    }else{

    /*do something else...*/

    }
```